# GAE - Having environment variables play nice with node.js apps

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, environment-variables, google-appengine-node

It seems like the environment variables in `app.yaml` are rendered in Python-like strings, where booleans like `true` become `True` and empty variables becomes `None`. Anyone have ideas on how to make it play nice with javascript without doing explicit conversion for all my variables?

```
const MY_ENV_VAR = (process.env.MY_ENV_VAR === 'None') ? null : process.env.MY_ENV_VAR;
```

Yes, I can write some function to do it. Wondering if anyone has a clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only additional available configurations related to Javascript are for Node.js and they are quite simple. As per the official documentation of the [app.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref), the option Javascript related is to set the `runtime` and that's it, unfortunately. **There is not direct way to configure better usage for the environment variables.**

Considering that and that, I agree with you, having better handling of environemt variables in Javascript would be better for a lot of cases. Due to that, I would recommend you to raise a Feature Request in Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0), so they can take a look at it and verify the possibility of implementing it in the future.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Hi @ahong please, consider upvoting or accepting this answer, in case it helped you in anyway, to solve your problem.